# Search for a specific ".exe" and open programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want my program to search a users computer for a file called "xonotic.exe" and open it. Xonotic is a video game if that helps. Inside it's parent folder it contains many other contents that .exe uses on launch.

```
        // Prepare the process to run
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

        // Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
        start.FileName = @"C:\Users\Landon\Desktop\Xonotic\xonotic.exe";

        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        start.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process.Start(start);
```

When I run my program in vs with this code it launches "xonotic.exe" but [(here's what it looks like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwcjd.png). That is a print of the screen on launch and if it looks like the text is going off the edge of my screen its because it is; what you see is what I see.

When I exit vs and just open "xonotic.exe" as I would normally it launches perfectly. My question is why would the programmatic way and the manual way open the same .exe in two different ways? Also when I get out of the buggy xonotic and hover over the icon to see the full view it says that you have reached this menu due to missing or unlocatable content/data. [(You can see what I'm talking about here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2GaI.png). Also if this part can be resolved easily is there a way to search for the .exe without having to know the filepath? I figured something like this would be super easy, all I want to do is launch program but it has been giving me a lot of grief.

Comment: did you try to set [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `WorkingDirectory` property first, then you may also try to set `UseShellExecute` property as well if needed:

```
string pathToExecutable = @"C:\Users\Landon\Desktop\Xonotic\xonotic.exe";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = pathToExecutable,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExecutable),
    UseShellExecute = true
};
```

UPDATE:

You can search on all drive in all folders, but this would be very time consuming. Here is the code for that:

```
string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
string pathToExecutable = String.Empty;

foreach (string drive in drives)
{
    pathToExecutable =
        Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(drive, "xonotic.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToExecutable))
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToExecutable))
{
    // We did not find the executable.
}
else
{
    // We found the executable. Now we can start it.
}
```

Comment: That worked thank you! but how can I implement this without knowing the full path at first? Is there a method that searches computer and returns the full path of a given .exe if it exists?

Comment: Thank you but I got an unauthorizedAccessException... I was getting these before that's why I started using the entire path instead of searching.

Comment: If it is possible then use [`System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prompt the user to select the xonotic.exe file. You can use it from a Console Application as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have here 3 different question, maybe give them numbers for each question.
And about your third question-
you must have a path of the root and then you can search for all the exe files in the subfolders

```
string PathOfEXE = @"C:\"; //or d:\ or whatever you want to be the root
 List<string> fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(PathOfEXE , "*.exe", 

System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
Directory.GetFiles(PathPractice, "*.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

            System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

            foreach (string fullPathfileName in fileEntries)
{
string fileName =System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPathfileName )
if (fileName=="xonotic.exe"){ //your code goes here
string pathToExecutable = fullPathfileName ; 



}



  }
```